# Как в mod_rewrite переписать GET переменные в адресной строке?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Есть ссылка типа site.ru/seachbyname/?n=привет&pg=1
как сделать в .htacces что б при переходе ссылка менялась на

site.ru/seachbyname/name/привет/page/1

Пробовал задать условие, но оно не работает
RewriteRule ^seachbyname/?n=(.*)&pg=(.*) seachbyname/name/$1/page/$2

Comment: Тут `site.ru/seachbyname/?n=привет&pg=1` GET переменные, а не POST.

Comment: Собственно, где POST?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так, например:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} n=(привет)&pg=(1)
RewriteRule ^(seachbyname/)$ /$1name/%1/page/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: не оно, не меняет вид ссылки